# Probability of getting odd at least once

Tags: probability

A fair die is tossed thrice. Find the probability of getting an odd number at least once.

Let E1 be the event corresponding to getting an odd number on the first throw, E2 on the second, and E3 on the third throw.

What we want to find is the probability of getting an odd number on the first or second or third throw i.e the probability of either/all of the events taking place which is P(E1 Union E2 Union E3).

Since these events are independent, it should be = P(E1)+P(E2)+P(E3) = 3/2 which is obviously incorrect. 
What did I do wrong here?

Comment: The odds of getting at least one, are 1 - (odds of getting none).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement is false:

> If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $P(A\lor B)=P(A)+P(B)$.

For a very simple counterexample, consider two coins with a strong bias, that turn up heads $90$% of the time. Clearly the odds of at least two heads isn’t $1.8$!

I think that the mistake you’re making is confusing *independent events* and *mutually exclusive events*. It’s quite possible to get an odd number on the first and on the second roll, and it’s perfectly possible to get two heads on the weighted coin. They’re independent events, not mutually exclusive events. The two things are very different.

In order to calculate $P(A\lor B)$ you need to use the following formula:

\begin{align*}P(A\lor B)=1-P(\neg A\land\neg B)&=1-P(\neg A)P(\neg B)\\
&=1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B))\end{align*}

Notice that the second equality only holds because $A$ and $B$ are independent. The other equalities hold for all events.